# maximum Data can be stored in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-farm

We want to store the 50TB per year,Can sharepoint 2013 can handle this.What about the performance if i have 50TB data in sharepoint.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It is depending upon on your design and how you many site collections / web applications you have.

50TB per year is alot of data and required alot of planning.

If you read the Limits of SharePoint 2013, ideal content Database size is 250Gb but supported Upto 4TB in different scenarios. That's mean One site collection can go upto 4 TB(as it is limit of Content DB) if we have only one site in DB. check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB

Another thing, you need very good specifications on your WFEs and also application servers. Search will be a big pain your case. So that's means you will hit the performance.

Another area to think about the Backup and recovery. 1st you need to store backup of more than 50TB data and then recovery.

Lastly i think you should see other options, even Office 365 can handle more than that but what MSFT doing on backend is still unknown.

I would also involve the MSFT arch for designing and opion options.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested storage per site collection is 100GB.  I'm not sure what the limitation for a farm is.  Given just the information on the site collections, you're looking at a minimum of 500 site collections/year.  That doesn't seem like the best practice to me, but there may be more info in the article below.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx)'s an article that has a lot of information on SP suggested limitations.